# Webresource name does not contain a valid prefix when trying to deploy C# Plugins

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I am in the process or leaning and teaching myself how to code plugins for CRM using CRM developer tools in Visual Studio 2012. I am coding plugins for crmlab. When trying to deploy my CRM solution, it keeps hitting me with this error time and time again:

**Webresources name does not contain a valid prefix**

I have checked the line where it says there is an issue but I cannot find anuything which is missing or which needs to be added.

```
<Target Name="WebResourcesDeploy" DependsOnTargets ="GetWebResourcesFromReferences">
<AddWebResource
            DiscoveryServer="$(CRMDiscoveryServer)"
            Port="$(CRMDiscoveryServerPort)"
            Scheme="$(CRMDiscoveryServerScheme)"
            Organization="$(CRMOrganization)"
            Password="$(CRMUserPassword)"
            UserName="$(CRMUserName)"
            Domain="$(CRMUserDomain)"
            SolutionName="$(CRMSolutionName)"

            Items="@(CRMWebResource)"
    XAPOutputs="@(_SilverlightXapFiles)"
    XAPReferences="@(_SilverlightApplications)"
    MSBuildProjectFullPath="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"        
                 />
```

Please help me as this is holding up my learning process!

Comment: Please show us the properties of the WebResources. My guess is that the prefix of the WebResource does not match the Publisher prefix for the solution.

Comment: Where can I find the properties to copy them here? Sorry I am very new to CRM and trying to teach myself.

Comment: You should see them in Visual Studio under Properties when you have a web resource file selected in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some other helpful information for you.[Web Resources for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473(v=crm.5).aspx)

> Relative URL
>
> When referencing a web resource from areas that do not support using
>   the $webresource: directive, a relative URL can be used. To enable
>   this, we recommend that you use a consistent naming convention for the
>   web resources that reflect a virtual file structure.
>
> The solution publisher’s customization prefix will always be included
>   as a prefix to the name of the web resource. This can represent a
>   virtual ”root” folder for all web resources added by that publisher.
>   You can then use the forward slash character (/) to simulate a folder
>   structure that will be honored by the web server.

Some helpful [Guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lezamax/archive/2010/10/21/crm-2011-web-resources-simulating-directories-and-the-importance-of-relative-paths.aspx) in an MSDN Blog (these can also found in the SDK):

> - Referencing web resources from one of our designers is straight    forward and the designer will take care of doing the right thing when 
>     referencing the web resource
> - Referencing web resources from CRM component that don’t have a    designer (e.g. Ribbon, Sitemap) should always use the $webresource
>     directive
> - Referencing web resources from other web resources (e.g. an html page    referencing a js library) should always use RELATIVE paths.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late. I had the same problem recently. I simply removed the default Silverlight project that Visual studio added to the solution and I was able to deploy the plugin successfully.